# Bootstrap Table Layout with space between rows with border around it without border between cells

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I would like to know if anyone knows how to do the style below using bootstrap 5?

[image]

The table has space between the rows and border around this rows, but no border between the columns.
I've been trying to recreate it for 4 hours without success.

My code is like that:

```
<style>
    .giro-table{
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing:0 15px;
    }
    .giro-table 
    .giro-table tr{border:1px solid #A8A8AD;}
    .giro-table th{background:#A8A8AD;}
    .giro-table td{padding:20px;}

  
  </style>

  <table class="table table-striped table-hover giro-table table-bordered" style="max-width:700px;margin:0 auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove default borders, then you need to set your custom borders.

See comments in the snippet below.

```css
.giro-table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 15px;
}

.giro-table .giro-table tr {
  border: 1px solid #A8A8AD;
}

.giro-table th {
  background: #A8A8AD;
}

.giro-table td {
  padding: 20px;
}

.table-bordered > :not(caption) > * > * {
  border-width: 0 !important; /* Remove default borders */
  border-top: 1px solid grey !important; /* Add custom border */
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important; /* Add custom border */
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid grey !important; /* Add custom border */
}

td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid grey !important; /* Add custom border */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover giro-table table-bordered" style="max-width:700px;margin:0 auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What classes do you have defined on your table or custom css that could cause this? Looks like you need to remove something.

Take a look at these examples https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/

It would be easier to answer if you provided your html.

Comment: I have updated with my code, but i can not achieve that style. It is not easy get the desired style using the examples provided by bootstrap since documentation does not have any example like that.